# VBA Excel userform autofill doesn't fill all the values

Tags: excel, vba

I have got the problem, and I don't know where the error might be.

I used the following code:

```
 Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
 Dim wks As Worksheet, wkf As Worksheet
 Set wks = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tracker")
 Set wkf = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Formulas")
 AppendToColumn wks, "A", JobID.Text  'Adds the TextBox3 into Col A & Last Blank Row
 AppendToColumn wks, "B", CoordName.Text
 AppendToColumn wks, "C", PlannerName.Text
 AppendToColumn wks, "D", Surveyor.Text
 AppendToColumn wks, "E", RRGuy.Text
 AppendToColumn wks, "F", DateBox.Text
 AppendToColumn wks, "G", TimeBox.Text
 AppendToColumn wks, "I", AddressBox.Text
 AppendToColumn wks, "J", CityBox.Text
 AppendToColumn wks, "K", PostcodeBox.Text
 AppendToColumn wks, "L", THPBox.Text
 AppendToColumn wks, "M", JointBox.Text
 AppendToColumn wks, "N", FibreBox.Text
 AppendToColumn wks, "O", FibreEquipmentBox.Text
 AppendToColumn wks, "P", SpareFibreBox.Text

 MsgBox ("All data has been added successfully")
 End Sub

 Private Function AppendToColumn(ByRef ws As Worksheet, _
                            ByVal column As Variant, _
                            ByVal value As Variant, _
                            Optional ByVal kindOfValue As DataType = DataValue) As Long
  '--- copies the given value to the first empty cell in the
  '    specified column. the "column" value can be either numeric
  '    or alphabetic. RETURNS the index of the last row
  Dim colIndex As Long
  Dim lastrow As Long
  Dim firstEmptyRow As Long
  With ws
    '--- quick conversion to make sure we have a numeric column index
    colIndex = IIf(IsNumeric(column), column, .Cells(1, column).Column)
    lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, colIndex).End(xlUp).Row
    '--- if the column is completely empty, the first empty row is 1,
    '    otherwise it's one row down from the last row
    firstEmptyRow = IIf(IsEmpty(.Cells(lastrow, colIndex)), 1, lastrow + 1)
    Select Case kindOfValue
    Case DataValue
        .Cells(firstEmptyRow, colIndex).value = value
    Case FormulaValue
        .Cells(firstEmptyRow, colIndex).Formula = value
    End Select
  End With
  AppendToColumn = lastrow
 End Function
```

My user form looks like this:

[image]

[image]

but the 3 last columns are empty, which means that these values are not coming out. Does anyone know the reason behind it?

Any help appreciated.

**UPDATE**

For another sort of code:

```
 Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
 Dim LastRowA As Long, LastRowB As Long, LastRowC As Long, lastrowD As Long, 
 LastrowE As Long, LastrowF As Long, LastrowG As Long, LastrowH As Long, 
 LastrowI As Long, LastrowJ As Long
 Dim lastrowK As Long, lastrowL As Long, lastrowM As Long, lastrowN As Long, 
 lastrowO As Long, lastrowP As Long
 Dim ws As Worksheet

 Set ws = Sheets("Tracker")

 LastRowA = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1 'Finds the last blank row
 LastRowB = ws.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
 LastRowC = ws.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
 lastrowD = ws.Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
 LastrowE = ws.Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
 LastrowF = ws.Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
 LastrowG = ws.Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
 LastrowH = ws.Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
 LastrowI = ws.Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
 LastrowJ = ws.Range("J" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
 lastrowK = ws.Range("K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
 lastrowL = ws.Range("L" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
 lastrowM = ws.Range("M" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
 lastrowN = ws.Range("N" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
 lastrowO = ws.Range("O" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
 lastrowP = ws.Range("P" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

 ws.Range("A" & LastRowA).value = JobID.Text 'Adds the TextBox3 into Col A & 
 Last Blank Row
'ws.Range("B" & LastRow).Value = ComboBox1.Text 'Adds the ComboBox1 into Col 
 B & Last Blank Row
 ws.Range("B" & LastRowB).value = CoordName.Text

 ws.Range("C" & LastRowC).value = PlannerName.Text
 ws.Range("D" & lastrowD).value = Surveyor.Text
 ws.Range("E" & LastrowE).value = RRGuy.Text
 ws.Range("F" & LastrowF).value = DateBox.Text
 ws.Range("G" & LastrowG).value = TimeBox.Text
 ws.Range("I" & LastrowI).value = AddressBox.Text
 ws.Range("J" & LastrowJ).value = CityBox.Text
 ws.Range("K" & lastrowK).value = PostcodeBox.Text
 ws.Range("L" & lastrowL).value = THPBox.Text
 ws.Range("M" & lastrowM).value = JointBox.Text
 ws.Range("N" & lastrowN).value = FibreBox.Text
 ws.Range("O" & lastrowO).value = FibreEquipmentBox.Text
 ws.Range("P" & lastrowP).value = SpareFibreBox.Text


 End Sub
```

The result is EXACTLY the same. The columns NOP are not populated. Is there somewhere a limit, which I don't know?

Thanks & Regards,

UPDATE:

[image]

Te values in three last columns N,O,P are still not coming.
All the boxes have their own names located as per below:

[image]

And this is how my full code looks like:

```
 Option Explicit

 Private Enum DataType
 DataValue
 FormulaValue
 End Enum


 Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
 Dim wks As Worksheet ' wkf As Worksheet
 Dim lastrowG As Long, LastrowS As Long, ListIndex As Long
 Set wks = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tracker")
 'Set wkf = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Formulas")
 AppendToColumn wks, "A", JobID.Text  'Adds the TextBox3 into Col A & Last 
 Blank Row
 AppendToColumn wks, "B", CoordName.Text
 AppendToColumn wks, "C", PlannerName.Text
 AppendToColumn wks, "D", Surveyor.Text
 AppendToColumn wks, "E", RRGuy.Text
 AppendToColumn wks, "F", DateBox.Text
 AppendToColumn wks, "G", TimeBox.Text
 AppendToColumn wks, "H", TimeEndBox.Text
 AppendToColumn wks, "I", AddressBox.Text
 AppendToColumn wks, "J", CityBox.Text
 AppendToColumn wks, "K", PostcodeBox.Text
 AppendToColumn wks, "L", THPBox.Text
 AppendToColumn wks, "M", JointBox.Text
 AppendToColumn wks, "N", FibreBox.Text
 AppendToColumn wks, "O", FibreEquipmentBox.Text
 AppendToColumn wks, "P", SpareFibreBox.Text


 MsgBox ("All data has been added successfully")
```

End Sub

```
 Private Function AppendToColumn(ByRef ws As Worksheet, _
                            ByVal column As Variant, _
                            ByVal value As Variant, _
                            Optional ByVal kindOfValue As DataType = 
  DataValue) As Long
'--- copies the given value to the first empty cell in the
'    specified column. the "column" value can be either numeric
'    or alphabetic. RETURNS the index of the last row
 Dim colIndex As Long
 Dim lastrow As Long
 Dim firstEmptyRow As Long
 With ws
    '--- quick conversion to make sure we have a numeric column index
    colIndex = IIf(IsNumeric(column), column, .Cells(1, column).Column)
    lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, colIndex).End(xlUp).Row
    '--- if the column is completely empty, the first empty row is 1,
    '    otherwise it's one row down from the last row
    firstEmptyRow = IIf(IsEmpty(.Cells(lastrow, colIndex)), 1, lastrow + 1)
    Select Case kindOfValue
    Case DataValue
        .Cells(firstEmptyRow, colIndex).value = value
    Case FormulaValue
        .Cells(firstEmptyRow, colIndex).Formula = value
    End Select
  End With
  AppendToColumn = lastrow
  End Function





    Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

   'Surveyor DropDown
    Surveyor.AddItem "Jonathon xxxxx"
    Surveyor.AddItem "Matthew xxxxx"
    Surveyor.AddItem "Andrew xxxxx"
     Surveyor.AddItem "Matt xxxxx"
  ' Rod & Rope guy dropdown
   RRGuy.AddItem "Julianxxxxx"
   RRGuy.AddItem "Rob xxxxx"
   RRGuy.AddItem "John xxxxx"
  'Jointbox dropdown
  JointBox.AddItem "Yes"
  JointBox.AddItem "No"
  'FibreBox DropDown
  FibreBox.AddItem "Yes"
  FibreBox.AddItem "No"
  'Fibreequipmentbox dropdown
  FibreEquipmentBox.AddItem "Yes"
  FibreEquipmentBox.AddItem "No"
 'Sparefibrebox dropdown
  SpareFibreBox.AddItem "Yes"
  SpareFibreBox.AddItem "No"
  End Sub

  Private Sub JointBox_Change()
  Dim answer As String
  answer = Me.JointBox.Text
  If answer = "No" Then
  Me.FibreBox.Enabled = False
  Me.FibreBox.Text = "Unknown"
  Me.FibreEquipmentBox.Enabled = False
  Me.SpareFibreBox.Enabled = False
  Else
  Me.FibreBox.Enabled = True
  Me.FibreEquipmentBox.Enabled = True
  Me.SpareFibreBox.Enabled = True
  End If
  End Sub
```

In the columns, NOP  I placed the formula

```
=IF(Mx="No","Unknown"," ")
```

where the x is the number of row i.e. M13,M14,M15 etc.

This formula doesn't impact into the situation, because when I try to input after clearcontents then everything is the same.

This is all I have.

Comment: Your `AppendToColumn` approach is wrong if you're working with a regular "table" dataset.  You should not be finding the first empty cell in *each column* and then placing individual values in those cells.  Any time the previous row or rows have a "gap" your data is going to get misplaced.  You need to fix the row once, and then place all the values in that same row.

Comment: What do you mean the empty cell? You mean, that because of column H, which is empty, the problem occur?

Comment: Let's say the last row of data is row 10, but some cells in that row are not occupied (ie. have no values)  When you add the next row of data, will all of the values go to row 11, or will some of them end up in row 10 (in previously empty cells)?  If you absolutely always have full rows of data with no gaps then there's no problem, but it's not a good design.

Comment: I have filled my missing column, which was column H. It doesn't work either.

Comment: Is it possible to use ListObject?

Comment: Do the values show up in the immediate window?

Comment: Are you sure the FibreBox.Text, FibreEquipmentBox.Text and SpareFibreBox.Text are correctly defined/mapped in your form?

Comment: What could be not correct? As you can see in the code where everything is on the same basis. Any errors I can check tomorrow morning.

Comment: 1) Check the "lastrow" value are what you expect (or there's sth down the columns?); 2) check the combox values as suggested by @Jones; 3) Could the form object being unload somewhere else, making the value no longer available? (worth to try to populate on column Q to know if it fails after N or just these three cols); 4) Make sure column N,O,P are not formatted as white text;      One more comment: avoid use variable names like "column", "value", which resemble properties name/function.

Comment: Good suggestions by @Oliver Leung. To elaborate a bit on what I meant: The code only shows the CommandButtonClick, not the Form. Hence, even if your code looks correct, if you have changed the last three list boxes for whatever reason, they may not have been renamed and still be called something like ListBox9. Hence, e.g. the FibreBox.Text value is not populated. Victor K's suggestion would give you a hint about this potential as well. Just add 'Debug.Print FibreBox.Text' to see if it shows up in the Immediate window.

Comment: I changed them all. No errors are shown, that's the worst thing

Comment: In my opition this code is limited to i.e.12,13 entries and when is bigger simply doesn't work. I probably must launch another user form in order to fill these 3 values.

Comment: I have updated my query, showed all I have.

Comment: Strange. So, you enter one entry in the form, press "Submit", and another entry, then "Submit", and so on. Correct?  If so, why column N,O,P does not show "Unknown" starting from the 3rd row (this is what FibreBox.text was set to)?  (btw, "Unknown" was not an "initialized" value). Do it mean the code works until you switch JointBox from No to Yes?  Again, have you check the values of the three combobox.text are correct?

Comment: See my answer. I found the error. As I dragged down the formula, the VBA excel treated it as the non-empty cell. It happened even when IF statement in the formula shown the " " (empty cell)as a result. In turn, I had all these entries further down in my spreadsheet (from the row 1001, because the formula was dragged to row 1000). In my image I gave an example of my bad, dragging the formula several cells down. You can see these entries underneath. This is why all these mess was about. Thank you for your contribution guys! I really appreciate your time.

Answer (score 0):

OK,

I found the silly error:

When in columns N,O,P I populated the formula

=IF(Mx="No","Unknown"," ")

and next dragged this formula down to row 1000 (my full list prediction). Then I found, that all the Textbox inputs have been populated.

Because the formula states, that if M13 is other than "No", then the values in N13, O13 and P13 should be empty, as per the `" "` expression.

Regrettably, VBA Excel don't treat these cells as empty and according to AppentToColumn function the data is to be added immediately underneath the range, where this formula has been populated.
Any Clearing contents at the top or in the middle of this range with populated formula won't help, because the new data will be still added below this range.

[image]

Instead of the Excel formula better is to modify the code in the If statement section:

```
  Private Sub JointBox_Change()
  Dim answer As String
  answer = Me.JointBox.Text
  If answer = "No" Then
  Me.FibreBox.Enabled = False
  Me.FibreBox.Text = "Unknown"
  Me.FibreEquipmentBox.Enabled = False
  Me.FibreEquipmentBox.Text = "Unknown"
  Me.SpareFibreBox.Enabled = False
  Me.SpareFibreBox.Text = "Unknown"
  Else
  Me.FibreBox.Enabled = True
  Me.FibreEquipmentBox.Enabled = True
  Me.SpareFibreBox.Enabled = True
  End If
  End Sub
```

adding the following line:

```
    Me.SpareFibreBox.Text = "Unknown"
```

to each Textbox, when disabled.

I hope it will be helpful for everyone, and no one will do a similar time-consuming mistake, as I did.